# My pygame crashes when I double click on its window's icon

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame

my script crashes with:

```
Fatal Python error: pygame_parachute: (pygame parachute) Segmentation FaultPython runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00001718 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\tee_c\Projects\abc\ABC.py", line 10 in <module>

Extension modules: pygame.base, pygame.constants, pygame.rect, pygame.rwobject, pygame.surflock, pygame.color, pygame.bufferproxy, pygame.math, pygame.surface, pygame.display, pygame.draw, pygame.event, pygame.imageext, pygame.image, pygame.joystick, pygame.key, pygame.mouse, pygame.time, pygame.mask, pygame.pixelcopy, pygame.transform, pygame.font, pygame.mixer_music, pygame.mixer, pygame.scrap, numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, PIL._imaging, pygame._freetype, win32api, _win32sysloader (total: 42);
```

when I double click on the png icon of the window. Here is my
code.

```
import easygui as eg
eg.msgbox(msg="press q when window opens to start script(not game).",title="note")
pygame.init()
logoIMG = pygame.image.load('ABClogo.png')
canvas=pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('ABC(game)')
pygame.display.set_icon(logoIMG)
while True:
    pygame.draw.rect(canvas, "red", pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: The indentation on the `.flip()` line looks wrong.  It should be called every iteration of the main loop, not just when `q` is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation on the `pygame.display.flip()` is wrong.   The `.flip()` writes all the window changes to the GUI, and is normally always called every loop iteration.

This version works for me (I don't have/want easygui):

```
import pygame

#import easygui as eg
#eg.msgbox(msg="press q when window opens to start script(not game).",title="note")

pygame.init()
logoIMG = pygame.image.load('ABCLogo.png')
canvas=pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('ABC(game)')
pygame.display.set_icon(logoIMG)

running = True
while running:
    pygame.draw.rect(canvas, "red", pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                print('q')
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```